# How would I fix this awful artifact shading?

Tags: shaders, normals, artifacts

I was making a gun model and couldnt figure out how to fix the awful shading on my models front without changing the detail of the model and Ive already tried [ Set from faces ], [ Average faces ] and [ Weighted normals ]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome Milottic please provide blend file. open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.As it would be more easier for me to explain the solution to you

Comment: Most probably your terrible shading is caused by the unconnected vertices on your mesh

Comment: ngons with "concave" shapes are generally a bad idea but it's really hard to tell from just the screenshots.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the moment you have large and non-planar ngons, it creates these artefacts:

[image]

You need to change your topology, for example this way:

[image]